# Prove $x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2+Mx^2y^2z^2\le \frac{5+M}{4}$, when $x+y+z=1+\sqrt{2}$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2\ge 2$

Tags: inequality

> **Problem.** For all $x,y,z\ge 0$ such that: $x+y+z=1+\sqrt{2}$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2\ge 2$, then $$x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2+Mx^2y^2z^2\le \frac{5+M}{4}, (*)$$for all $M \ge \dfrac{540 \sqrt{2}+162}{191}$.

The problem is belong to one of my friends who is very good at using program to prove inequalities. I tried very much and here is my attempts.

The equality case is $(a,b,c)=\left(1,\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$ which clearly imply my idea is not good enough. Anyway, I write it here and hope the reader give me more advices.

I rewrite  $(*)$ as $$f(r)=-Mr^2+(2+2\sqrt{2})r+\frac{M+5}{4}-q^2\ge 0.$$where $0\le q=ab+bc+ca\le\dfrac{1+2\sqrt{2}}{2}; 0\le r=abc\le \left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}}{3}\right)^3.$

We prove two case

1. $0\le q\le\sqrt{\dfrac{M+5}{4}}:$ It is easy: $$r(-Mr+2+2\sqrt{2})\ge r\left(-M.\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{3}\right)^3+2+2\sqrt{2}\right)>0.$$
2. $\sqrt{\dfrac{M+5}{4}}\le q\le \dfrac{1+2\sqrt{2}}{2}.$ By Schur third degree, $0\le r\le \dfrac{(1+\sqrt{2})(4q-3-2\sqrt{2})}{9}.$

Hence, $f(r)$ is concave in $\left[\dfrac{(1+\sqrt{2})(4q-3-2\sqrt{2})}{9};\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}}{3}\right)^3\right]$, so we calculate two point value:
\begin{align*}
    & f\left(\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})(4q-3-2\sqrt{2})}{9}\right)\\
    &=\frac{-M(3+2\sqrt{2})}{81}(4q-3-2\sqrt{2})^2+\frac{2(3+2\sqrt{2})}{9}(4q-3-2\sqrt{2})+\frac{5+M}{4}-q^2
\end{align*}
and: $$f\left(\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2}}{3}\right)^3\right)=K-q^2.$$
I realise that the sign of both yields are depend on specific value of $M$.

For example, when $M=\dfrac{540 \sqrt{2}+162}{191}$; $q=\dfrac{1+2\sqrt{2}}{2}$, we get two negative value.

I am stuck with the aproach using *pqr* and function. If someone have an idea how to continue, please tell me.

I also tried *uvw* which I saw effectiveness in case *pqr* doesn't help.

Set $x+y+z=3u, xy+yz+zx=3v^2, xyz=w^3$. In the next part, I just homogenize the starting inequality.
$$x^2+y^2+z^2\ge2.\left(\frac{x+y+z}{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)^2\implies 9u^2-6v^2\ge 2.\left(\frac{3u}{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)^2,$$Hence
$$\frac{3+6\sqrt{2}}{6+4\sqrt{2}}\ge \left(\frac{v}{u}\right)^2 (1).$$
After multiply $(x+y+z)^2$ both side, the OP becomes
$$(x+y+z)^2(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)+M(3+2\sqrt{2})x^2y^2z^2\le \frac{5+M}{4}.\left(\frac{x+y+z}{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)^6(3+2\sqrt{2}),$$which is *uvw* form as
$$9u^2\left(9v^4-6uw^3\right)+M(3+2\sqrt{2})w^6\le \frac{729(M+5)}{68+48\sqrt{2}}.u^6$$
By the idea using *uvw* in case concave function, I rewrite above form as a function of $w^3$,
$$f(w^3)=-M(3+2\sqrt{2})w^6-9u^2\left(9v^4-6uw^3\right)+\frac{729(M+5)}{68+48\sqrt{2}}.u^6\ge 0.$$ We need to check two cases,

1.$w^3=0:$ put $x=0$, notice that $3u^2\ge 4v^2,$
$$81u^2v^4\left(\frac{9(M+5)}{68+48\sqrt{2}}.\frac{u^4}{v^4}-1\right)>81u^2v^4\left(\frac{9(M+5)}{68+48\sqrt{2}}.\frac{16}{9}-1\right)>0$$
2. Two of $x,y,z$ are equal. I am really confused here by $(1)$. The linkage of $u,v$ is quite strange to me. I think I can not set all arbitrary $(x,y,z)$. Hope we truly continue it.

I move to another idea using $(1).$

Rewrite as below:$$f(w^3)=-M(3+2\sqrt{2}).\left(\frac{w}{u}\right)^6-27\left(3.\left(\frac{v}{u}\right)^4-2\left(\frac{w}{u}\right)^3\right)+\frac{729(M+5)}{68+48\sqrt{2}}\ge 0.$$Now,setting
$$\frac{3+6\sqrt{2}}{6+4\sqrt{2}}\ge \left(\frac{v}{u}\right)^2=t;4t-3\le \left(\frac{w}{u}\right)^3=s\le 1,$$
which I used Schur third degree: $$w^3\ge \frac{3u(12v^2-9u^2)}{9}=u(4v^2-3u^2)\implies \left(\frac{w}{u}\right)^3\ge 4\left(\frac{v}{u}\right)^2-3.$$Finally, we work with a function,
$$f(s)=-M(3+2\sqrt{2}).s^2-27\left(3t^2-2s\right)+\frac{729(M+5)}{68+48\sqrt{2}}\ge 0,$$where $4t-3\le s\le 1$ and $0\le t\le \dfrac{3+6\sqrt{2}}{6+4\sqrt{2}}.$

It seems I am lost here. All my approach here is not good enough since the $M$ is strong.

I will try more. Thank you for watching and help!

Comment: Anyone can help me ?